# Having same String in 2 Vec in Rust?

Tags: string, vector, rust

Not sure if this is best title for my question, if there is better, please suggest.

This is sample of working code, that is approximation of my real code, but it is fine for demonstration.

```
fn main() {
    let data = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string(), ];
    
    let mut v1 = Vec::new();
    let mut v2 = Vec::new();
    for i in data {
        v1.push(i.to_owned());
        v2.push(i.to_owned());
    }
    // to make it read-only, so that I do not make same stupid mistake later
    let v1 = v1;
    let v2 = v2;
    
    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

Basically I have vectors of strings and I need to make N(already 2, but there will be more, around 20) vectors that need to have access to Strings from original vector.

One solution that I have is to use to_owned(). And if I understand it correctly this is basically creating copy of String, so I end up with 2 same Strings in memory, which I find unnecessary wasted and would like to avoid it.

**What is best way in Rust to do it ?**

One solution that I have found is to convert original data Vec to &str, but not sure if that is best/correct way to do it in Rust(I am still beginner in Rust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more context on why you need those vectors or what you want to do with them, I see two ways you can take.

1. **Use references**

This approach stores the string once in the `data` variable and stores references to these strings in the other vectors.

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string(), ];
    
    let mut v1 = Vec::new();
    let mut v2 = Vec::new();
    for i in &data {
        v1.push(i);
        v2.push(i);
    }
    // to make it read-only, so that I do not make same stupid mistake later
    let v1 = v1;
    let v2 = v2;
    
    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

2. **Use reference-counting smart pointers**

This approach stores the strings on the heap, and uses the `Arc` type from the standard library which ensures via reference counting that the string on the heap will be deleted once all vectors have been deleted. The clone operation is cheap, it only increases the reference count.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let data = ["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()]
        .into_iter().map(|i| Arc::new(i)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
    let mut v1 = Vec::new();
    let mut v2 = Vec::new();
    for i in &data {
        v1.push(Arc::clone(i));
        v2.push(Arc::clone(i));
    }
    // to make it read-only, so that I do not make same stupid mistake later
    let v1 = v1;
    let v2 = v2;
    
    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

Comment: Note that without any more context I'd prefer `Rc` over `Arc` as it's less overhead and Rust will complain if you need to upgrade to an `Arc` anyways.

Comment: Doing benchmark of downloading files with different approach (multiple/single clients, threads), so I need structure of urls(always same) and file_path where to download(each approach in different directory). 
But I changed approach, now I have one Vec of url, and one Vec for each approach, and iter/zip thru both in same time.
Probably there is something better, but happy with this so far.

Comment: Additional inquiry. Example one, with references, was not possible for my original use-case because I was making new variable inside of it. I have made code example with Rc demonstrating same point at https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fd310ba7ce058a628f9aa3730542a3f.
Can I get some feedback is this correct implementation ?

Comment: @cafce25 For an inexperienced user, I'd always recommend `Arc` over `Rc` as the error message that Sync/Send/whateveritis is missing can be quite hard to understand, but technically you're right

Comment: @WebOrCode Your code looks good. However, keep in mind that you could also take a reference to the entire vector/array if the vectors are the exact same for all your benchmarks